# Capture variable from fetch return in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, react-native

Im try get a answer in my FETCH request:

File 1: PHP file and recived the login credential and return TRUE or FALSE:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "$json_str\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

echo  '{ "mystatus": "TRUE" } '; //THIS IS MY VARIABLE STATUS
```

File 2: Send the login credentials, but in this file dont know haw can capture "mystatus"

```
fetch("http://xxxxxx/app/login.php", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "same-origin",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "payload": "1234"
    })
  })

.then(function(data) {
    // Dont can capture mystatus

console.log(data);
});
```

How can get mystatus in File 2?

Thansk!

Comment: You said `mode: "same-origin",` and then using an *absolute* URI. Is this really a same origin request?

Comment: Look in the Console. Are any errors reported?

Comment: Look in the Network tab. Can you see the request? Can you see the response? Is the response formatted the way you expect?

Comment: `echo  '{ "mystatus": "TRUE" } '; ` should be fine, but get in the habit of using `json_encode` to avoid trivial errors breaking everything. Handcrafted JSON attracts trivial errors.

Comment: with fetch() there has to be 2 then() and the second then() has the data and I hope you are doing the same thing

Comment: @Quentin yes in network --> answer see: { "status": "TRUE" } , how can catch this?

Answer (score 0):

The initial response from the fetch api is a promise and contains a response object. You need to do something with that object. Usually its a json object so you would use the json() method to get its content.

```
 fetch("http://xxxxxx/app/login.php", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "same-origin",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "payload": "1234"
    })
  })
  .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
  }).then(function(data){
    console.lot(JSON.stringify(data);
  });
```

You should read the documentation. I would start here: [Using Fetch | MDN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)